# Refresh a page when delete is performed in odoo?

Tags: python-2.7, return, odoo-8, page-refresh, unlink

I want to refresh the view page when delete is performed.

I tried unlink() method I see some codes to reload the page.

```
return { 'type': 'ir.actions.client', 'tag': 'reload', }
```

But when I use unlink() method

```
@api.multi

def unlink(self):


   return models.Model.unlink(self)
```

It has to return the unlink() to delete the record so I can not call the return for reload.

I tried this

```
@api.multi

def unlink(self):

      x={'type': 'ir.actions.client', 'type': 'reload',}

    return models.Model.unlink(self),x
```

But its not working.

Any other suggestions to reload/refresh the view page of odoo when delete is performed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
@api.multi
def unlink(self):

  return {'type': 'ir.actions.client', 'type': 'reload'}
```

It works for me